# Cannot delete branches in GitHub as a repository admin

Tags: github

I cannot delete branches via GitHub UI even though I have admin rights for the repository.
The delete button is disabled:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have Branch protection rules defined that don't allow deleting branches.

For that go to repository settings -> Branches.
Under `Branch protection rules` edit the rule that matches the branch(es) you are not allowed to delete. Scroll down and see if `Allow deletions` is enabled.